# asp.net core blazor webassembly subtlecrypto - how to use a custom secret key

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, blazor, blazor-webassembly, subtlecrypto

We are trying to integrate Subtlecrypto into our blazor webassembly app. It seems this is the only cryptography package that blazor wasm supports.

According to the [official example](https://github.com/memd24/Blazor.SubtleCrypto), there is not a way to change/custom the secret key. If the secret is assigned at startup, the key is fixed and used across the application:

```
using Blazor.SubtleCrypto;

builder.Services.AddSubtleCrypto(opt => 
    opt.Key = "ELE9xOyAyJHCsIPLMbbZHQ7pVy7WUlvZ60y5WkKDGMSw5xh5IM54kUPlycKmHF9VGtYUilglL8iePLwr" 
    );
```

Or one can use random key and iv that the application has no control.

In our app we hope to ask the user to enter a key, which is used to encrypt some data. A fixed key can work but it seems less secure.

Is there a way to achieve a custom secret key?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Below is what I did:

```
    var options = new CryptoOptions() { Key = "some_secret"};
    var crypto = new CryptoService(jsRuntime, options);
    string s = "abc";
    CryptoResult encrypted = await crypto.EncryptAsync(s);

    Console.WriteLine("Encrypted: " + encrypted.Value);

    string d = await crypto.DecryptAsync(encrypted.Value);

    Console.WriteLine("Decrypted: " + d);
```